# How to make a shadow on left of Box like 3d effect?

Tags: dart, flutter, shadow

I'm implementing UI from dribble to practice my ability. Below images are original and my implementation.

[image]

[image]

I implemented almost, but I can't implement below side's shadow effect, how can do that?

My implementation is just stack two Card and move to left a bit. But I think it is not optimal solution, isn't it?

Comment: see [boxShadow](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration/boxShadow.html)

Comment: I used it, but I cannot implement

Comment: whats unclear in [this](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxShadow/BoxShadow.html) constructor?

Comment: What property I have to use? Offset didn't work

Comment: Does this fit your requirement http://prntscr.com/m4t0we? If yes, I can post my solution :)

Comment: check for example how they made [kElevationToShadow](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/kElevationToShadow-constant.html) - as you can see `offset` does work

Answer (score 0):

So my little solution  for this one is just you need to build a stack witha container behind and a card in the front  with some shadows to obtain this 3d Animation